# Prevent addEventListener() run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that runs speech recognition when I click button `start`, when speech recognition is over some actions should be started. I use `addEventListener('audioend', ()=>...)` to track the event. Everything work as expected, but now I am adding another functionality to stop listening when I click the same button and the function should be completed also. But I faced an issue with `addEventListener` that runs despite the `return` key word.

```
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition.getRecognition()
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

  function playSong() {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying) //when I click 'Play' button again it changes to 'Stop'
    if (listening) { //verify if speech recognition listening 
      SpeechRecognition.stopListening()
      console.log('Should stop here') 
      return   //I try to use return but it doesn't help, in any case addEventListener runs next
    }else if {
      recognition.addEventListener('audioend', () => {
      console.log('Some other actions')
    }
   ........
}
```

Comment: Every time you click your play button while not "listening" you are adding a new event listener to recognition. I'm assuming you don't want to do that. Either add a single event listener outside of `playSong` or pass `{ once: true }` as options to `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return you need to remove the event listener

```
const dosomeaction = () => {

    console.log("do some action")
};
recognition.addEventListener('audioend', dosomeaction)
```

In this way you add the event listiner so you can remove it by this way

```
recognition.removeEventListener('audioend', dosomeaction)
```

Comment: You have to pass the same function to the `removeEventListener` you've passed to the `addEventListener` as a second argument.

Comment: Yes you need to pass the methods as second argument  i have fixed the solution

Comment: @MohamadAlZohbie Can `removeEventListener` goes before `addEventListener`? Because in my case it goes before, but if I put it before, it doesn't bring any affect.